# No option to update user database in Visual Studio ASP.NET publish

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have now tried to deploy an asp.net MVC application on both MVC4 and MVC5. Whenever I get to the settings for the publish there is no option to: "Update Database" and therefore no option  to "Configure database updates".

Is there something that I have missed out in the tiresome and complicated set of hoops that I have to jump through to get an asp.net MVC application deployed? I have tried on and off for the past few months to get an MVC application deployed but I never seem to manage to get the User database part correct. I have got all other parts working. I moved onto MVC 5 because it is said that the user authentication has been updated. It is still not working and I am getting the same problem.

By all means tell me if there is another post about this topic. I have tried to find a similar post on SO but have had no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be irrelevant with regards to deploying with MVC 5. The problem is in the fact that asp.net have not written individual instructions for Visual Studio 2013/ MVC 5. The system for the member database is different for MVC 5 and therefore this step is not needed.